# .htaccess change directory image

Tags: wordpress, image, .htaccess

I have this blog and I've looking around the way to change my image path but nothing really works for me.

This is the URL where my image will display:

`http://localhost/blog/article1/`

inside is located `<img src="images/logo.jpg" />`

but with this URL the server searches for: 
`localhost/blog/article1/images/logo.jpg`

And the real URL for my image is: `localhost/blog/images/logo.jpg`

I've tried with a lot of options but so far none have worked for me.

Note: the blog is made in WordPress, but some articles come with code from another migration, so I probably cannot change the whole articles.

What I need is to elevate `subdirectory` to `localhost/blog/images`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you might get away with redirecting all calls that end with /back/back1.gif to that directory, so it wouldn't matter where the call came from. That does mean you should not wish to call this to some other subedirectory, but I imagine you don't.

something like this (guessing here, cann't test, so read up on the rwriting there :)

```
RewriteRule     ^(.*)/images/$(.*) http://test.example.com/back/$2 [L,R=301]
```

basically you are rewriting everything that has '/images/' in it to that static adress, pasting whatever was after images after the new asdress (the $2 thingy) and then indicating that this is the last command to parse (to stop strange things in the htaccess) and that you want a 301 (permanently moved) code to be sent.